# geocoder declaration null pointer exception in service class

Tags: java, android, geocoding

when i put reverse geocoder function into service class and trying to call in activity ,, i got null pointer exception ..
this is my class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    String tempAddress;
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            String locationgps=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(locationgps);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS/Data roaming is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
public  String getMyLocationAddress() {

        Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {

              double latitude=getLatitude();
              double longitude=getLongitude();
              //Place your latitude and longitude
              List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);

              if(addresses != null) {

                  Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                  StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();

                  for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                  }
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am at: "+strAddress.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 // myAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());
                  tempAddress=strAddress.toString();

                 return tempAddress; 
                  //Intent intent = new Intent("MyCustomIntent");
                           // add data to the Intent
                          // intent.putExtra("strAddress",strAddress.toString());
                          // intent.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
                         //  sendBroadcast(intent);




                //  Intent intent = new Intent (Menu.this,IncomingSms.class);
                 // intent.putExtra("strAddress",strAddress.toString());
                //  sendBroadcast(intent);

              }

              else
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  //myAddress.setText("No location found..!");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tidak bisa Menerima Alamat ,, harap cek jaringan dan gps hp anda!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 showSettingsAlert();}
                 tempAddress="Could not Retrive Address!";
                         return tempAddress;
        }

}
```

and this is my activity class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.xml.transform.Templates;

import mo.locationtracking.GPSTracker;
import mo.sms.IncomingSms;
import info.MonitoringObjek.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button bTambah;
    private Button bLihat;
    //private Button blokasi;
    GPSTracker gps;
    private TextView myAddress;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.menu);
          myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(info.MonitoringObjek.R.id.lokasisekarang);
        //  blokasi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lokasi);
        //  blokasi.setOnClickListener(this);
          bTambah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tambah);
          bTambah.setOnClickListener(this);
          bLihat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_view);
          bLihat.setOnClickListener(this);
         // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(Menu.this);
         // check if GPS enabled        
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                //double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                //double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                //Geocoder geocoder;
                //myAddress.setText("Latitude: "+latitude+"Longitude: "+longitude);
                String tempAddress=gps.getMyLocationAddress();
                myAddress.setText("I am at: " +tempAddress);

                gps.stopUsingGPS();
                // \n is for new line
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {

            case R.id.button_tambah :
                Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateData.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.button_view :
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this, ViewData.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
        }
    }



}
```

and this is my logcat:

```
05-28 14:47:14.187: E/Trace(5031): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.MonitoringObjek/mo.database.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at mo.locationtracking.GPSTracker.getMyLocationAddress(GPSTracker.java:213)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at mo.database.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:54)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
05-28 14:47:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(5031):     ... 11 more
```

i see in[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521592/geocoder-initialization-fails) it's say geocoder must declare inside on create in activity .. is that impossible to declare in service class? i need that geocoder still update even my application is closed..

Comment: can you highlight the line `Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:54)`

Comment: this is line 54 in menu oncreate sir String tempAddress=gps.getMyLocationAddress();
          myAddress.setText("I am at: " +tempAddress);

Answer (score 0):

The Location from the android application is not that much accurate you can call the google api webservice using get method and parse the json result and you can get Area Block city street etc
it is more accurate than default one